# ZK Combobox event not triggering in MVVM

Tags: java, mvvm, web-applications, combobox, zk

I'm trying to understand how ZKoss works, in particolar using the MVVM pattern.

I'm using ZK8.0.2.2 CE on JDK8 and wildfly 10.

I have a combobox and a Grid. I want the combobox onSelect event to trigger the Grid update. The grid is updated with the selected item from the combobox as parameter.

Problem is, the @Command method that is supposed to be called by onSelect is never called and the update is never triggered.

And another thing: if I got how data binding works right, the onSelect argument on the Combobox shouldn't even be necessary. The Grid is bound to a ListModel in the ViewModel (allMedia) by the argument model="@load(vm.allMedia)"

So if allMedia changes, the grid should update automatically (similarly to what happens in JavaFX with bound properties). Obviously this is not happening.

This is the .zul file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<zk xmlns="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul">
    <window apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer" viewModel="@id('vm') @init('mediadb.gui.MediaViewModel')">
        <vbox pack="center" align="top" width="990px" height="600px">
            <panel title="Search" border="normal" vflex="true">
                <panelchildren>
                    <label value="Type" class="boxlabel" />
                    <combobox id="cmbType" width="150px" model="@load(vm.allType)" selectedItem="@bind(vm.actualType)"
                        onSelect="@Command('updateTable')">
                        <template name="model">
                            <comboitem label="@load(each.label)" />
                        </template>
                    </combobox>
                </panelchildren>
            </panel>
            <panel title="Media" border="normal" vflex="true">
                <panelchildren>
                    <grid id="mediaGrid" mold="paging" autopaging="true"
                          emptyMessage="No results" pagingPosition="both"
                          vflex="true" model="@load(vm.allMedia)">
                        <columns sizable="true">
                            <column hflex="1" label="ID" align="center" sort="auto(id)" />
                            <column hflex="3" label="Serial#" align="center" sort="auto(serialNumber)" />
                            <column hflex="3" label="Support Label" align="center" sort="auto(supportLabel)" />
                            <column hflex="3" label="User Label" align="center" sort="auto(userLabel)" />
                            <column hflex="2" label="Added" align="center" sort="auto(addDate)" />
                        </columns>
                        <template name="model">
                            <row vflex="1">
                                <label value="@load(each.id)" />
                                <label value="@load(each.serialNumber)" />
                                <label value="@load(each.supportLabel)" />
                                <label value="@load(each.userLabel)" />
                                <label value="@load(each.addDate) @converter('formatedDate', format='dd/MM/yyyy')" />
                            </row>
                        </template>
                    </grid>
                </panelchildren>
            </panel>
        </vbox>
    </window>
</zk>
```

and this is the ModelView:

```
package mediadb.gui;

import mediadb.db.DataProvider;
import mediadb.entity.MdbCategory;
import mediadb.entity.MdbMedia;
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.Command;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.Init;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.NotifyChange;
import org.zkoss.zul.ListModel;
import org.zkoss.zul.ListModelList;

public class MediaViewModel {

    private DataProvider db = null;
    private ListModel<MdbCategory> allType = null;
    private ArrayList<MdbMedia> allMediaData = null;
    private ListModel<MdbMedia> allMedia = null;
    private MdbCategory actualType = null;

    @Init
    public void init() {
        try {
            db = DataProvider.getInstance();
            allType = new ListModelList<>(db.getCategories());
            actualType = allType.getElementAt(0);

            allMediaData = new ArrayList();
            allMedia = new ListModelList<>(allMediaData);

        } catch (IOException | SQLException | PropertyVetoException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(MediaViewModel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
    }

    @Command
    public void updateTable() {
        allMediaData.clear();
        allMediaData.addAll(db.getMedia(actualType.getLabel()));
    }

    public ListModel<MdbCategory> getAllType() {
        return allType;
    }

    public void setAllType(ListModel<MdbCategory> allType) {
        this.allType = allType;
    }

    public MdbCategory getActualType() {
        return actualType;
    }

    public void setActualType(MdbCategory actualType) {
        this.actualType = actualType;
    }

    public ListModel<MdbMedia> getAllMedia() {
        return allMedia;
    }
}
```

(I'm omitting data beans and db access that is beside the point of the question.)

Am I doing it wrong? Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Command` in your code have an uppercase in C letter change it into `@command` and it should be working fine.

change it into :

```
<combobox id="cmbType" width="150px" model="@load(vm.allType)" 
   selectedItem="@bind(vm.actualType)" onSelect="@command('updateTable')">
```

and dont forget add `@NotifyChange("allMediaData")` on your updateTable method

```
@Command
@NotifyChange({"allMediaData","allMedia"})
public void updateTable() {
    allMediaData.clear();
    allMediaData.addAll(db.getMedia(actualType.getLabel()));
    allMedia.AddAll(allMediaData);
}
```

Comment: Nope, it still doesn't work. I changed the argument as you suggested (I didn't knew they were case sensitive) but it behaves exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, still no luck. I had tried that already actually (even if it should not be necessary because the model of then Grid is bound to the allMedia object on read - IF I understood the logic correctly).

Comment: @NoWone havee you tried add all data to AllMedia in updateTable method? try my new updated answer

Comment: Unfortunately, `allMedia` is a `ListModel<>` so it has no `addAll()` method, but your suggestion was right nonetheless. After modifying `allMediaData` I just create a new `allMedia` and notify. Now it works. I still wonder why you have to manually notify the changes of a **bound** variable, it doesn't make too much sense to me, but ok. Thanks!